# ffmpeg asyncts usage

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I use the new asyncts in ffmpeg (or avconv)? Which is the right syntax?

> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.wav -vcodec copy -strict experimental -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -f flv -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -filter_complex "asyncts=max_comp" 3.mp4

Generates:

> [asyncts filter @ 0x2a58640] Missing key or no key/value separator
>   found after key 'max_comp' [asyncts @ 0x2952380] Error parsing options
>   string 'max_comp'. Error initializing filter 'asyncts' with args
>   'max_comp'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#asyncts), it appears that `max_comp` takes an argument:

> ‘max_comp’
>   Maximum compensation in samples per second.

So you should set it as you would any other filter argument:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.wav ... -filter_complex "asyncts=max_comp=44100" 3.mp4
```

<sup>(Of course I don't what's actually an appropriate value for your situation.)</sup>

Comment: According to the documentation, in order to use `asyncts` `max_comp` you must also set `compensate=1`, so the settings should be `-filter_complex asyncts=compensate=1:max_comp=44100`, though to be honest I didn't see a difference between setting `compensate` and without - they both seem to have solved my problem.